# Как зациклить ввод данных?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = input('Ваш nickname')    
n = input('Ваше имя')
if n == '':
    ...
```

Если переменная `n` будет пуста, тогда запросить ввод имени и nickname'a опять, как такое реализовать?

Comment: В смысле вернутся к переменной? Потребовать её ввести ещё раз?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1]: while True:
   ...:     name = input('Name: ')
   ...:     nickname = input('Nickname: ')
   ...:     if name and nickname:
   ...:         break # Если введён ник и имя, делаем что-то и обрываем цикл
```

Можно сделать еще такой функцией:

```
In [5]: def user_info():
   ...:     name = input('Name: ')
   ...:     nickname = input('Nickname: ')
   ...:     if name and nickname:
   ...:         return name, nickname
   ...:     return user_info()
   ...:

In [6]: user_info()
Name: My name
Nickname: # Пусто
# А тут мы заполняем все поля
Name: My name
Nickname: My nickname
Out[6]: ('My name', 'My nickname')
```

И вызывать её в любом нужном участке программы.

Answer (score 0):

```
user_info = ['']
while not all(user_info):
    user_info = list(map(input, ('name:', 'nickname:', )))
```

#

```
def set_user_info(info: dict) -> None:
    while not all(info.values()):
        for k in info:
            if not info[k]: info[k] = input(k)

user_info = {'name:': None, 'nickname:': None}
set_user_info(user_info)
```