# Как зациклить калькулятор и при нажатии X он переставал работать?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
a = input ("Які дії будем виконувати (+ ,- ,/ ,*) : " )
b = float(input ("Введіть перше число : "))
c = float(input ("Введіть друге число : "))
if a == "+":
    d = b + c
    print ("Буде короче : " + str(d))

elif a == "*":
    g = b * c
    print ("Ти шо не знаєш шо це буде : " + str(g))

elif a == "-":
    e =  b - c
    print (e)

if a == "/":
    try:
        p = b / c
        print (p)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("На ноль делить нельзя")
```

Comment: Вам необходимо весь код запихнуть в while(True), потом после инициализации 'a' добавить условие, if a == 'X': break, и всё

Comment: Простите но можете обяснить што такое инициализация.Я токо по Python прочытал 1 книгу и посмотрель видеоуроки.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как зациклить ввод данных?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685754/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Answer (score 1):

```
listA = ['+', '-', '/', '*']

while True:
    a = input ("\nЯкі дії будем виконувати (+ ,- ,/ ,*) : " )

    if a.lower() == 'x':
        break

    if not a in listA:
        print("Вы не правильно ввели действие, повторите.")
        continue


    b = float(input ("Введіть перше число : "))
    c = float(input ("Введіть друге число : "))

    if a == "+":
        d = b + c
        print ("Буде короче : " + str(d))
    elif a == "*":
        g = b * c
        print ("Ти шо не знаєш шо це буде : " + str(g))
    elif a == "-":
        e =  b - c
        print ( "{} - {} = {}".format(b, c, e))
    elif a == "/":
        if c:
            p = b / c
            print (p)
        else:
            print("На ноль делить нельзя")
```

Comment: а теперь качаем python 3.8, и вместо while True:, делаем while (a := input ("Які дії будем виконувати (+ ,- ,/ ,*) : " )) != 'X':(;

Answer (score 1):

тоже самое, что и у ответа ранее, но с адаптацией к версии 3.8:

```python
listA = ['+', '-', '/', '*']

while (a := input ("Які дії будем виконувати (+ ,- ,/ ,*) : " )) != 'X':
    if not a in listA:
        print("Вы не правильно ввели действие, повторите.")
        continue


    b = float(input ("Введіть перше число : "))
    c = float(input ("Введіть друге число : "))

    if a == "+":
        print (f"Буде короче :  {b + c = }")
    elif a == "*":
        print (f"Ти шо не знаєш шо це буде :  {b * c = }")
    elif a == "-":
        print ( f"{b - c = }")
    elif a == "/":
        if c:
            print (f'{b / c = }')
        else:
            print("На ноль делить нельзя")
```