# Повторение кода в питоне

Tags: python

у меня есть такой код, учу питон и хочу написать програмку где спрашивает про таблицу умножения и если юзер отвечает правельно то добавляет ему 10 баллов, хочу что бы после оканчании кода юзер мог играть еше так что я задаю ему вопрос хочеш ли играть еше. помогите в этом. вот код.

```
import random as rm

user_gamer = 0

num1 = rm.randint(1, 10)
num2 = rm.randint(1, 10)

print(num1, "*", num2)
question = int(input("What is your answer to this multiplication? "))


def multiplication(x, y) -> int:
    calculated_value = x * y
    return calculated_value


if num1 * num2 == question:
    user_gamer += 10
    print(f"Correct! you gain a 10 points, now you have ", user_gamer, "points")
else:
    user_gamer -= 10
    print(f"Incorrect! you lose a 10 points, now you have ", user_gamer, "points")

print(f"result is", multiplication(num1, num2))
wanna_play_again = input("Would you like to play again? ")

if wanna_play_again == "yes":
    
elif wanna_play_again == "no":
    exit()
```

Comment: Стоит отформатировать код в вопросе для начала )

Comment: Воспользуйтесь циклом.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как зациклить ввод данных?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685754/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import random as rm

user_gamer = 0

while True:
    num1 = rm.randint(1, 10)
    num2 = rm.randint(1, 10)

    print(num1, "*", num2)
    question = int(input("What is your answer to this multiplication? "))


    def multiplication(x, y) -> int:
        calculated_value = x * y
        return calculated_value


    if num1 * num2 == question:
        user_gamer += 10
        print(f"Correct! you gain a 10 points, now you have ", user_gamer, "points")
    else:
        user_gamer -= 10
        print(f"Incorrect! you lose a 10 points, now you have ", user_gamer, "points")

    print(f"result is", multiplication(num1, num2))
    wanna_play_again = input("Would you like to play again? ")

    if wanna_play_again != "yes":
        pass
```

А еще лучше использовать f-string:

```
print(f"Correct! you gain a 10 points, now you have {user_gamer} points")
```

А в твоём примере f в print не используется.

Comment: И если не жалко отметь потом решением пжлст :)

Comment: спасибо, еше 1 вопрос как бы вы исправили код если бы хотели что бы он спросил про продолжение игры только после того как у юзера будет 100 очков?

Comment: @Zailox Как по мне, просто закинуть весь код в `while True:` - это как то не `True`. К тому же, используя ваш ответ - игра начнется при любом вводе, что как то нарушает логику. **(Я бы ваш ответ не принял)**

Comment: хотя я только начел изучать питон то мне тоже все в вайл не очень нравится идея потому что в реалной ситуации не думаю что можно будет так вес код закинуть просто туда так как будет больше функционала же в будушем, я думаю должно быть решения по акуратнее, может вы могли бы его предложить?

Comment: @Amgarak "бесконечный цикл" `while True:` с выходом из него по `break` или `return` - совершенно нормальный приём программирования, не вижу проблем. Вот то, что в данном случае использован `exit()` - это излишне, конечно.

Comment: @CrazyElf а я и не говорю что цикл с бесконечным условием это плохо, плох сам ответ, что-то на уровне моего комментария "добавьте цикл"(только воспринят совет был слишком буквально). Я упорно не понимаю тех кто его лайкает наверно за гениальную строчку while True и pass в условии.

Comment: @TornikeInalishvili спасибо за отметку, сейчас освобожусь и апдейтну

Comment: @Amgarak сказано - сделано, человеку нужно просто зациклить вопрос, насчёт любого ввода - сейчас починю

Comment: @CrazyElf нету смысла в break, т.к. после цикла ничего нет, можно просто выйти

Comment: @Zailox Я не люблю `exit()`, потому что мало ли какие ещё дела могут быть у программы, может ей ещё что-то нужно сделать напоследок - напечатать какой-то результат, например, или ещё что-то, что нужно делать при проходе по любым веткам кода, а тут мы просто вышли и всё )

Comment: @Zailox как почините, дайте знать;)

Comment: @Zailox смотрю так и не починили свой бесценный ответ, сказано, но не сделано... 

Comment: @Amgarak занят был, забыл немног

Comment: @TornikeInalishvili ну тут вариантов почти нету, кроме вайл, прийдется либо пихать весь код (надеюсь вы пользуетесь не блокнотом), либо засунуть нужную часть кода в def и писать уже *while True: x() #x - функция*

Comment: @CrazyElf если ему нужно будет написать что-нибудь напоследок - я изменю

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь циклом while перед логикой приложения, где ответ "no" будет приводить к выходу из цикла, а ответ "yes" продолжит его выполнение